VS Code logpoints on Embedded device not evaluating variables
I can get logpoints to show up just fine without any extrapolation {}.
Once I add anything like {myVariable} or $CALLER, they are just treated as string and logged but not evaluated.
Do logpoints with extrapolation work for embedded devices? I am using cortex debug and Microsoft embedded tools. Like I said log points do work to a certain extent.
logpoint expression: myCounter = {myCounter} caller = $CALLER caller = {$CALLER}
For the variables I did make sure they were in context or global variables.
